# Hat sich das Geschlecht von „Antwort“ mit der Zeit geändert?

Tags: etymology, gender

> **This question also has an answer here (in English):**
>
> - [Why is “Antwort” feminine, if “Wort” is neutral?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23300/)

Vor ein paar Wochen habe ich im Buch von Bohnenblust *Pour Bien Savoir l’Allemand* (Payot, 1930) gelesen, dass das Substantiv *Antwort* früher sächlich verwendet worden, aber der Gebrauch damals schon (das heißt im Jahre 1930!) veraltet gewesen sei.

Ich habe das Buch nicht zur Hand, aber es schien mir zuverlässig. Übrigens wäre *das Antwort* ganz logisch, da man *das Wort* sagt.

Stimmt Bohnenblusts Behauptung und wenn ja: Wann hat sich das Geschlecht von *Antwort* geändert?

Comment: *Erklärung* Ich weiß, dass im Titel Anführungszeichen um "das Antwort" herum stehen sollten. In diesem Fall habe ich sie wegen eines Wortspiels weggelassen: man kann die Frage verstehen entweder als "kennen Sie die Antwort auf meine Frage?" oder "Kennen Sie den sächlichen Gebrauch des Wortes Antwort "? Und ich gestehe, dass ich mich von dem Reiz der Provokation nicht losreißen konnte...Ich bitte also die Benutzer, keine Anführungszeichen in den Titel hinein zu editieren (es geschah vor ein paar Minuten: daher diese Erklärung).

Comment: @splattne: Was meinst Du? Ich werde mich an deine Entscheidung halten, und gegebenenfalls meine Kommentare auslöschen.

Comment: Ich bin hin- und hergerissen. Ich finde das Wortspiel reizvoll. Die Frage wird damit zum Blickfang. Allerdings könnte sie bei Leuten, die Deutsch nicht so gut beherrschen auch Verwirrung stiften. Ich lass das mal so und bitte andere, evtl. ihre Meinung dazu zu äußern.

Comment: Auf den ersten Blick wollte ich auch die Frage editieren, um den Titel zu korrigieren. Aber nach dem Lesen war dann doch klar, worum es geht :)

Comment: @splattne: Danke fur die gemäßigte und vernünftige Antwort. Ich will mich nicht mehr an dieser Frage beteiligen und verlasse mich völlig auf Dich und auf die anderen Benutzer: entscheidet!

Comment: @splattne: Deine letzte Änderung verstehe ich nicht. Wolltest Du "worden" wirklich entfernen?

Comment: @Hendrik_Vogt Ich hatte die ursprüngliche Änderung gemacht, da die Zeiten in der Originalfassung nicht korrekt waren; jetzt ist mir aufgefallen, dass der Satz verworren klingt. Die Verkürzung ist hier zulässig; der Satz wird insgesamt stilistisch besser. Verbesserungsvorschläge sind natürlich immer willkommen.

Comment: @splattne: (Benutze einfach "@Hendrik", oder "@HendrikVogt" wenn Du willst. Mit Unterstrich bekomme ich keine Banachrichtigung `:-(`) Ich weiß nicht genau, was das Problem mit den Zeiten war - meinst Du, weil der "früher sächlich verwendet" Teil _vor_ "veraltet" lag? Ich sehe auch nicht ganz, dass die Verkürzung zulässig war, aber das kann eine Bildungslücke meinerseits sein. Die jetzige Version gefällt mir.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Der Grimm bestätigt dies (Auszug, Hervorhebungen von mir):

> antwort schwankt von altersher zwischen n. und f. goth. andavaurdi, alts. andwordi, nnl. antwoord, fries. ondwarde, onderde sind stets neutral, auch bei den meisten ahd. antwurti, nur schweift O. ins f. (Graff 1, 1023); mhd. lassen die stellen das geschlecht oft ungewis, doch hat man den stumpfen nom. antwurt für weiblich, antwürte für neutral zu nehmen
>
> […]
>
> allmälich überwiegt das f., wie noch entschiedner im nhd. antwort. Suso setzte entwürt. **Luther scheint von natur für das neutrum**: das antwort des heiligen geists. 3, 362; solch sei gesagt vom stumpfen und rauchen antwort. 8, 124b; […] **doch darf in den drei letzten stellen ein und mein bei Luther auch weiblichen wörtern zustehn. deutliches f. schreibt er in folgenden**: und der könig gab dem volk ein harte antwort. 1 kön. 12, 13; man wartet der antwort von dir. Hiob 34, 33; eine linde antwort stillet den zorn. spr. Sal. 15, 1. spätere ausgaben führen das f. noch weiter ein. **Melanchthon aber und andere hochdeutschere schriftsteller brauchen das wort immer weiblich**, z. b. christliche antwort. vorr. zur apol. der augsb. conf. Wenn aber späterhin Wieland 9, 97 schreibt an antworts statt, Lessing 2, 164 und sicher noch öfter, ich glaubte das sei antworts genug; so zuckt darin das alte neutrum nach oder etwas niederdeutsches.

Schon zu Luthers Zeiten gab es also beide Formen und Schriftsteller, die bereits komplett die weibliche Form verwendet haben, während er selbst noch zwischen Neutrum und Femininum schwankte. Auch Luthers Werk wurde dann aber später weiter in die weibliche Form geändert. Bei den [NGrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=das%20Antwort,ein%20Antwort,einem%20Antwort&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3) findet sich keine nennenswerte Verwendung, allerdings ist das deutschsprachige Korpus auch erst etwa ab dem 19. Jahrhundert einigermaßen vernünftig ausgebildet. Das spricht aber natürlich dafür, dass in den letzten Jahrhunderten die Antwort bereits weiblich ist.

Comment: Sehr interessantes andavaurdi (wie immer), OregonGhost. Danke!

Comment: Mitten im Grimmschen Auszug lese ich  "man wartet der antwort von dir". Folgte damals auf "warten" der Dativ oder der Genitiv ?

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg: Es scheint, dass es früher eine wörtliche Bedeutung von "warten" gab, die anders war als heute ("wohin schauen, seine aufmerksamkeit auf etwas richten"), jedoch auch eine der heutigen ähnliche übertragene Bedeutung, die früher mit Genitiv stand: "auch warten mit dem gen. erscheint häufig in übertragenem gebrauch." - aber das habe ich nur eben beim Überfliegen gefunden. Es gab aber auch damals schon Formen mit Akkusativ und mit Dativ, die aber eher andere Bedeutungen hatten. Das ist auch ein [ziemlich langer Artikel](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=27,2125,63).

Comment: Danke, OregonGhost.

Answer (score 17):

Als Ergänzung und weitere Quelle sei noch das [Etymologische Wörterbuch des Deutschen (nach Pfeifer)](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Antwort&view=1) zitiert:

> **Antwort** f. ‘Erwiderung’ (auf eine Frage, auf das an jmdn. gerichtete Wort), ahd. *antwurti* (8. Jh.), mhd. *antwürte*, *antwurt* ist eine Kollektivbildung zu dem unter *Wort* (s. d.) behandelten Substantiv mit dem Präfix *ant-* ‘(ent)gegen’ (s. *ent-*). Ursprünglich ist *Antwort* also ‘Gegenrede’. **Von Haus aus ein Neutrum, folgt es schon in ahd. und mhd. Zeit teilweise der Deklination ähnlich gebildeter Feminina**.

Comment: Danke für den fantastischen Link und den Auszug (mit Hervorhebung!), Takkat.