# Why is "Antwort" feminine, if "Wort" is neutral?

Tags: gender

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>
> - [Hat sich das Geschlecht von “Antwort” mit der Zeit geändert?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1882/hat-sich-das-geschlecht-von-antwort-mit-der-zeit-ge%C3%A4ndert)

Shouldn't they have the same grammatical gender, since they have the same stem?

Just idle curiosity on my part.

Comment: I'll make it very short.
They both come from the same family and are related to (among others) Latin "Verbum". The ancestors of "Antwort" were feminine and neuter, depending on region. Feminine prevailed, probably also because the prefix "ant" stopped being productive and felt less and less "prefix"-y, so people don't immediately think "Wort" when hearing/saying "Antwort"

Comment: @Emanuel: now that the post was reopened you should add your comment above as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You’re not that wrong with the assumption. While it’s not necessary for similar-looking words to share a common precursor (cf. *malen* and *mahlen*, indistinguishable when heard), that’s actually the case here: The word *Wort* is derived from Proto-Germanic **wurdą* while *Antwort* stems from the same root with the prefix **anda-* meaning *against*. So originally, the *Antwort* was the *counter-word* or the *counter-speach*. Ironically, the English *answer* and the Scandinavian *svar* stem from a Proto-Germanic synonym **andaswarō* which shares a common root with *to swear*.

But you know, Proto-Germanic was a long time ago, and languages live and mutate. Most of the words that contained the prefix **anta* suffered a sound change turning the *ant-* into *ent-*. *Antwort* was, for some reason, exempt from this shift. Newer composite words would now be formed with the new prefix *ent-* and people stopped recognising *ant-* as a prefix — much like the *ur-* in *Urlaub* is no longer recognised as a prefix. That basically meant that *Antwort* and *Wort* would further develop separately.

Originally, this word did have the neuter gender. However,

> Von Haus aus ein Neutrum, folgt es schon in ahd. und mhd. Zeit teilweise der Deklination ähnlich gebildeter Feminina.
>   (Etymologic dictionary on [dwds.de](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Antwort))

(translated) *in Old and Middle High German, the word started following the declension of similarly formed feminine words,* and thus started acquiring feminine gender. Both genders apparantly coexisted for quite some time, each one being preferred in some regions, until finally — *ant-* no longer being recognised as a prefix — the feminine prevailed.

Even the declensed formes have now drifted apart: The plural of *Wort* is either *Worte* or *Wörter*, the plural of *Antwort* is *Antworten*. I’m not sure whether the different declensions and the change in gender happened at the same time or if one followed the other (but it doesn’t really matter).

Comment: If anybody knows which *ähnlich gebildete Feminina* could be meant by the quote please fire away so I can add them.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, +1. It is hard to judge all of this information without knowing old or middle German grammar. It would be very interested if someone could elaborate on that.

Comment: Great answer!! Glad you made the effort. It was way worth it.

Comment: \*anda- does not strictly mean *against*; *Gegenwort* obviously has quite a different semantic coloration, for one. Cp. *onto* for one, and \*ana "on". Or Latin *ante* and *anti* both from the same Proto-Indo-European root. Also note the dualism in *again, against*, *wieder* and *wider* (and at least one more pair like that, which escapes me at the moment).

Comment: I would imagine "ähnlich gebildete Feminina" would be referring to abstract verbal derivations.
tun, Tat;
-fahren, -fahrt;
-kommen, -kunft;
mögen, Macht;
können, Kunst;
gönnen, Gunst;
antworten, Antwort;
As a non native speaker, it always made sense to me that Antwort was feminine as it fit into this schema. Not to mention other verbs ending in "-e" and not "-(s)t", such as Lüge, Wäsche, and Nahme (lügen, waschen, nehmen). From the early days I was greatly helped with gender by this site: http://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/Wortbildung/Wortbildung.html

Comment: More:
graben, Gruft;
drehen, Draht;
biegen, Bucht;
sehen, Sicht;
tragen, Tracht;
gebären, Geburt;
(geschehen, Geschichte); 
schreiben, Schrift;
wiegen, Wucht;
und vielleicht auch "arbeiten, Arbeit".

Answer (score 7):

Ich hoffe, dass es in Ordnung ist, wenn ich auf Deutsch antworte. Bei Bedarf übersetzte ich den Text auch ins Englische.

Der Begriff »Antwort« ist - Im Gegensatz zur Vermutung des Fragenstellers - nicht von »Wort« abgeleitet. Das erkennt man gut an der Herkunft der beiden Begriffe:

**Etymologie von »Antwort«:**

> nhd (neuhochdeutsch): **Antwort**
>   mhd (mittelhochdeutsch): **antwürte**
>   ahd (althochdeutsch): **antwurti**

*Quelle: DUDEN - Das Herkunftswörterbuch, 3. Auflage, 2001, Seite 42.*

Dem steht die **Etymologie von »Wort«** gegenüber:

> nhd (neuhochdeutsch): **Wort**
>   mhd (mittelhochdeutsch): **wort**
>   ahd (althochdeutsch): **wort**

*Quelle: DUDEN - Das Herkunftswörterbuch, 3. Auflage, 2001, Seite 934.*

Die Angleichung der Endsilbe von *antwurti/antwürte* an das Wort *wort* geschah erst spät, nämlich beim Übergang vom Mittelhochdeutschen zum Neuhochdeutschen.

Comment: Laut DWDS: "antwurt ist eine Kollektivbildung zu dem unter  "Wort" (s. d.) behandelten Substantiv mit dem Präfix ant- ‘(ent)gegen’" – Das deutet dann doch auf eine Verwandschaft hin.

Comment: @Em1: Wer ist DWDS?

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: https://www.google.com/search?q=dwds Es führt allerdings ‚nur‘ andere Quellen zusammen, insofern wäre als Quellenangabe korrekter: _Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen_

Comment: Tolles Wörterbuch. Da stehen nicht mal »Sackerl«, »Bankomat« oder »Beiried« drinnen. Jedes zweite Wort, das typisch für das Österreichische Standard-Deutsch ist, fehlt. Das DWDS sollte nicht »Digitales Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache« heißen, sondern »Wörterbuch der Sprache Deutschlands«.

Comment: Deine "Etymology" ist tatsächlich nur eine Übersicht über verschiedene Schreibweisen. Der Zusammenhang zu Germanisch "wurda" fehlt. Beide Wörter sind durchaus eng verwandt. -1. Noch eine weitere Bemerkung: da diese Frage schon in einer Deutschen Version vorliegt, ist der einzige Grund, warum sie hier nochmal steht, dass sie in Englisch ist. Da machen dann auch nur Englische Antworten Sinn. Die deutsche Antwort kannst du einfach beim deutschsprachigen Thread hinschreiben.

Comment: Was DWDS angeht... der Fakt, dass offenbar viele Standardwörter des Österreichischen fehlen sagt nichts über die Qualität der vorhanden Einträge zu tun. Du kannst die gleiche Etymologie in Grimms Wörterbuch und im Duden Etymologie finden. Ich konzidiere, dass du sagst "nicht abgeleitet". Das mag sein. Sie haben sich aus dem selben Stamm entwickelt. Wenn man die Antwort jedoch "internetmäßig" konsumiert, dann wird man höchstwahrscheinlich mitnehmen, dass beide wenig miteinander zu tun haben.

Comment: @Emanuel: Ich bewerte ein Wörterbuch, das vorgibt ein Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache zu sein, sehr wohl danach, ob gängige Begriffe meiner Muttersprache darin abgebildet sind. Und meine Muttersprache ist nunmal nicht Deutsches Deutsch, sondern Österreichisches Deutsch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast... kannst du ja auch. Aber du kannst nicht vom Umfang auf die Qualität schließen. Ein Wörterbuch mit nur 3 Einträgen ist natürlich Scheiße, aber die Einträge selbst können 1A sein. Da muss man differenzieren und hier geht es um die Qualität eines einzigen Eintrags.

Comment: @Emanuel: Ein Wörterbuch mit nur 3 Einträgen (oder meinetwegen 20.000) ist auch dann nutzlos, wenn die vorhandenen Einträge preisgekrönt und goldumrandet sind. Das DWDS mag ja für das Deutsche Deutsch ein hervorragendes Wörterbuch sein, aber es gibt eben nicht nur dieses eine Deutsch. Und wenn dieses Wörterbuch behauptet ein Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache zu sein, dann muss es den Wortschatz aller Varietäten abdecken. Andernfalls wäre es ja auch durchaus legitim, es als »Wörterbuch des Deutschen Deutsch" (oder ähnlich) zu bezeichnen. Dann steht drauf was wirklich drin ist, und alles ist gut.

Comment: Das bestreite ich doch garnicht. Aber es geht eben hier nicht um das Wörterbuch sondern um einen einzigen Eintrag. Die Frage ist, wie ist die Qualität des Eintrags zu "Antwort". Umd die bewerten zu können, musst du mit anderen Quellen vergleichen. Deine Meinung zum Wörterbuch insgesamt (ob richtig oder nicht) ist irrelevant. Du aber hast sie benutzt um einen Kommentar zu kontern. Und da wollte ich klarstellen, dass dieser Konter nicht funktioniert.

Comment: Falls du bei meiner Aussage »Tolles Wörterbuch. Da stehen nicht mal ...« verstanden haben solltest: »Der konkrete Eintrag zum Wort "Antwort" in diesem Wörterbuch ist mangelhaft«, dann muss ich dir leider mitteilen, dass du glaubst etwas verstanden zu haben, das ich niemals gesagt oder gemeint habe. Ich habe niemals auch nur mit einer Silbe diesen einen Eintrag kritisiert. Das was ich kritisiert habe ist das Wörterbuch als ganzes, bzw. dessen Bezeichnung als Wörterbuch der »Deutschen Sprache« wo es doch nur ein Wörterbuch der »Sprache Deutschlands« ist.

Comment: Hubert wollte eigentlich sagen, der Author sei sowohl als auch voreingenommen, wenn es um den Sprachschatz, als auch die Etymologie geht--welcher Author? Na wohl @Emanuel Denn man zumindest fürhalten, dass für die Kollektivbildung ein anderer Genus erwartet werden kann und die weitere Verwandschaft dann auch egal ist. Ob demnach überhaupt eine wirklich enge Verwandschaft vorliegt, dürfte angesichts des bekannten Synonyms zudem fraglich bleiben. Nicht ein-eindeutig.

Comment: @vectory: 1. Warum wärmst du einen Thread auf, der ziemlich genau 5 Jahre lange inaktiv war? (Du antwortest auf einen Kommentar, den ich im Mai 2015 geschrieben habe.) 2. Ich verstehe kein Wort. Bitte bilde ganze und vor allem grammatisch einigermaßen korrekte Sätze. Und lies bitte alles, was du anderen zur Lektüre zumuten willst, vorher mindestens einmal selbst durch bevor du es postest.

Comment: 1. Der Thread erschien halt auf der Startseite. 2. Ich habe ausversehen ein oder zwei Worte vergessen. Ich versuchs noch mal: Deine flambierten Kommentare legen m.M.n. nahe, du sprächest über Voreingenommenheit. Das ist richtig. Der Author--sei es der Wörterbuchauthor oder hier der Kommentator--ist notwendiger Weise voreingenommen. Das betrifft einerseits die Korpusauswahl, was dich wohl stört. Das betrifft eventuel auch die Etymologie, was mich wiederum stört, insb. bzgl. "ursprünglich ...", da darin Geradlinigkeit angenommen wird, die angesichts der Sprachvielfalt kaum haltbar ist.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a German, but when I did my Ph.D. in Goettingen, I had to take German courses. I reached to C2. There were many questions regarding irregularities in German language. One of them is this word, Antwort with it's feminine article. I got the same question. One day I jumped into a book that explained the change. It said it is normal in a language to change in the process of time, although it bypasses the regularity.

So it was Antwurte or Antwürte in the past. Through time it changed into Antwort. Since it was ended with -e, it was a feminine. When it changed into Antwort, the gender remains as feminine.

So the book informed me.

Answer (score 0):

**Antwort** is a singularized former plural of wort (würte).

De würte -> de antwürte. logically, the ›Antwort‹ (answer) consists of multiple words, hence the former plural wich became a singular in modern german but kept its article.

Comment: Care to provide some evidence? The dictionaries cited elsewhere don't agree with you (_Kollektivbildung_ does not mean plural, see _Geäst_ for an example).